# Creating a box plot with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a box plot that shows the variance for values from 8 cities. With them being displayed using facets based on education attainment levels.
Here is `data frame 1` 
[image: data frame]

for example I want to see how much variance there is between `HS_grad` numbers for all the cities. 
[image: facets groupings]

#### Update

Here is `data frame 2`
[image: data frame2]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! Please read up on [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Based on your screenshots, you will need to convert your dataset into a "long format" rather than the current "wide format". I think the code below should achieve what you want.

```
# Install packages
install.packages("tidyverse")

# Load
library(tidyverse)

# "df" is your data frame as shown in your screenshot
df %>%
  # Change from wide to long format
  gather(City, Value, -EA) %>%
  # Plot
  ggplot(aes(x = EA, y = Value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ City) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thank you! this is headed in the right direction,but.....
How do I create a new column that assigns the education category to a value,

Chicago   22.9   HS_Grad

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. Are you saying you want a boxplot for each EA which uses the numbers from all cities? In that case just comment out the `facet_wrap` line above. Or if you want each EA in its own facet, change the ggplot line to `x = 0` and `facet_wrap(~ EA)`

Comment: Providing your data or a reproducible example would help.